# Why am I getting (run-time error '13': ) type mismatch when looping across a (sometimes-empty) variant?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, worksheet-function

I'm using the `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)` event (for the first time) to build dynamic validation lists in a single worksheet. Cells A2 and B2 house the validation drop-down lists; and cell B2 is contingent on cell A2; and cell A2 is contingent on the rest of the values in Column A that are beyond A5

**[ in this list, the final selection in B2 will yield other values associated with it: DB-like ]**

This is how is how the subroutine is intended to work after the sheet has changed:

VARIABLE DECLARATIONS* `variant, range, string`

SET THREE RANGE OBJECTS A, B, & C where B & C use A (the last used cell in a range)

CHECK THE POSITION OF THE TARGET

1. if the target is in the first column (column A),

1a) see if the target is in the second row (A2)...if it is, then clear contents in the B range, call function1 that returns an *array* of filtered values and their cell positions on the active sheet >> assign that returned array to a variant variable1 that is used in a subsequent call

- call function1
- variable1 = function1
- call function2 (`Target`, variable1)

2. if the target is in the second column (B),

2a) see if the target is in the second row (B2)...if it is, then clear contents in the C range, call a function to populate the cells in C range based on what is in B2; if the target is not in B2, nothing else is supposed to happen

3. if the target is anywhere else

...nothing happens

---

The issue occurs at call function2; when I watch the variables/add breaks at value changes, function1 and variable1 seem to receive the values in properly, but when function2 is called, it's throwing the runtime error and telling me that the variable1 is empty...

I do not know if the changes to ranges being made during initial execution count as subsequent changes to the worksheet or if they all count as the same change

I HAVE HAD SUCCESS getting the drop-list in A2 and B2 to work, but the changes in B2 didn't promote the final change so the code was reconfigured...the reconfigured code is producing a strange error chase

I did try deactivating/activating enableEvents, (also new to me) but it did not change the result...below is the code from function2 (arg1, arg2)...if everything works before it, I don't see why it returns error

```
Call StateFinder                                           'calls the function that builds address 
SearchAll50 = StateFinder                                  'sets the new searchable array to it's value
Call ListBuilder(Target, SearchAll50)                      'builds a list of values in the target cell
                                
                                
'a variable set that stores the Target's address
'-----------------------------------------------
StateGPS = GetPlaceGPS(Target.Value, SearchAll50)           'the Target address will be set to variable
```

GetPlaceGPS throws the error

```
Function GetPlaceGPS(ByVal SelectedPlace As String, ByVal MadeList As Variant) As String
'the returned address will then be used to set the range used to search cities

    Dim i As Long     
    For i = LBound(MadeList) To UBound(MadeList)
    
        If MadeList(i)(0) = SelectedPlace Then
            'compares the first value of the ith row to the selected state
            'once the state is found GetStateGPS is set to the sheet address
                
             GetPlaceGPS = MadeList(i)(1)
            
            'exit the function once the value is properly set
             Exit For
        End If        
    Next i
    
End Function
```

Comment: which line in function throws the error? And did you want ByRef MadeList() As String

Comment: Hi @QHarr, I've noticed that _**SOMETIMES**_ the function has difficulty assigning values to the SearchAll50 variant which means it's passing an empty/unassigned variant to the GetPlaceGPS() function

When the For Loop starts inside of GetPlaceGPS(), **the line that initiates the loop is the one that gets highlighted in error**. At best, I can deduce that the function is trying to loop through the LBound of the array (....which is 0) to the Ubound of an erroneously emptied array (...also assumed to be 0)

The code breaks here and none of the values previously assigned get values.

Answer (score 1):

Character type arguments must be used and must be declared as variables.

```
Dim myString As String
myString = target.Value
StateGPS = GetPlaceGPS(myString, SearchAll50) '<~~ Character type arguments must be used and must be declared as variables.
```

Comment: Thanks @Dy.Lee, but I'm afraid that I might need some clarity on your advice: earlier in the code, StateGPS is declared as a string variable, but is not set to an initial value, nor does it ever appear until its value is set to be equal to the result of the function

**Q-01:** What do you mean by "character type arguments"? I searched MSDN but did not find the answer that I was looking for...a link would be great here

**Q-02:** In your answer, I noticed that you took the value of Target and set it equal to an internal variable >> what is the difference in doing this VS using Target.value?

Comment: @ArthurL., In your user-defined function, you have specified the format for the arguments. If another executable code does not declare the argument as the same type variable, it is recognized as a different type and an error is returned.

Comment: A new string variable is equal to the target value (per the suggestion)...the code throws it's first error when setting the new string variable to the value of the target

Here is all of the live code before the error line:

`
Dim TargetValue As String
Dim TargetPlace As Range
    
Dim SearchAll50 As Variant
Dim CitySearch As Variant
Dim LastR2Cell As Range
Dim StatChange As Range
    
Dim CityChange As Range
Dim StateGPS As String
Dim CityGPS As String
   
TargetValue = Target.Value  'sets the internal variable to the target value
`
still Run time error '13': Type Mismatch

Comment: What's odd here is that the code WAS working before the run-time error began in interrupt the sequence...I don't see where the type mismatches are being introduced

The code became unresponsive (meaning it stopped responding to ANY changes made on the sheet). After restarting Excel and re-opening the workbook, it became responsive again, but the run-time error persists